# Column chart without gaps in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Which property of what part of the chart control allows you to change the gap between the columns in a column chart?

I just want to remove the gap, but I cannot find where this can be done.

Edit: this is using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: Could you add tags that can describe if it is winforms/asp.net/wpf/phone and what chart control it is?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find a way to achieve this using custom properties:

```
Chart1.Series(0)("PointWidth") = "1"
```